# Silverstripe 3 - Why is data not being passed to the template

Tags: silverstripe

I'm trying to use the YouTube widget but it appears that there are issues with it in Silverstripe 3 and it is not passing the DataObjectSet to the template and as a result, I cannot pass my data to the template. All the values are displayed correctly in the CMS, it is only in the template that they are not passed so it appears to be an issue with DataObjectSet in SS3. I've searched pretty extensively but cannot find any mentions of it's deprecation in SS3.

```
class YoutubeWidget extends Widget{
    static $title = "My favorite video";
    static $cmsTitle = "Your tube widget";
    static $description = "This widget can embed clips from youtube.com";

    static $db = array(
        "Width" => "Int",
        "Height" => "Int",
        "URL" => "Text",
        "Title" => "Text"
    );

    static $defaults = array(
        "Width" => 283,
        "Height" => 182
    );

    function getCMSFields(){
        return new FieldList(
            new NumericField("Width", "Video Width"),
            new NumericField("Height", "Video Height"),
            new TextField("URL", "Video URL"),
            new TextField("Title","Title or a note about this video")
        );
    }

    function GetVideoData(){
        $output = new DataObjectSet();
        $output->push(
            new ArrayData(
                array(
                    "Width" => $this->Width,
                    "Height" => $this->Height,
                    "URL" => $this->URL,
                    "Title" => $this->Title
                )
            )
        );      
        return $output;
    }
}
```

None of the variables are being populated in the template.

```
<% control GetVideoData %>
    <object width="$Width" height="$Height">
        <param name="movie" value="$URL"></param>
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
        <embed src="$URL" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" width="$Width" height="$Height"></embed>
    </object>

    <p style="text-align:center;">$Title</p>
<% end_control %>
```

If I wrap the control in <% if GetVideoData %> it doesn't access the control, indicating that nothing is being returned, this also happens even if I change the GetVideoData function to simply return a string. ie `return "asdf";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a change in SS3. I just needed to drop the "get" from the control call in the template;

```
<% if VideoData %>
    <% control VideoData %>
    <% end_control %>
<% end_if %>
```

Answer (score 2):

SS3 will now use `<% loop VideoData %>` or `<% with VideoData %>` instead of `<% control VideoData %>`.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com!